# How to remove active class upon clicking into another label tag

Tags: angular

I have a div label that loops into each product price, and
clicking the product price set the active class into it's label element tag.

My question is how can I remove the active class if I click into another label element?

```
<div class="btn-group cx-cont" *ngFor="let price of product.price" data-toggle="buttons" >
    <label class="btn btn-primary " id="cart-label" [ngClass]="{'active' : price.active == true }">
        <input type="radio" class="cart-check" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" (click)="selectProduct(price.id,price, price.unit)" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="cart-price">{{price.price | currency: 'USD':true}}</div> <div class="cart-unit">{{price.unit}}</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

I have the `[ngClass]="{'active' : price.active == true }"` the price.active is set into it's component on the selectProduct method

```
selectProduct(id, price, unit) {
this.price_id = id;
this.price = price;
this.price.active = true;
this.unit = unit;
this.isClassVisible = true;
this.selectedProd = true;
// console.log(this.cart);
```

}

Comment: Just store `active_price_id` and in template `{'active': active_price_id == price.id}`

Comment: What should be the initial value of the active_price_id ?

Comment: If you want to make all `label`s inactive -> some id that definitely cannot exist in your application. If `priceId` is sql's `autoincrement` index, then you can set "-1", for example. Or make your variable type of `any` (if you use typescript) and assign `null`...

Answer (score 0):

The one of the ways to achieve this is:

```
[ngClass]="price.active ? 'active' : ''"
```